# JQuery DataTables - Search not working, sData is null error

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a dataTable I am using to list information but hit a snag. I can no longer filter the results with the search bar! Whenever I type in, it just says no results found (even though there are over 500 records when no search term is entered). Everything is displayed as it should be when there is no search term.

Here is the error message in firebug:

```
sData is null
return sData.replace(/\n/g," ").replace( /<.*?>/g, "" );
```

Here is my table initialization:

```
var oTable = $('#dataTable').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [[ 2, "desc" ]],
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sAjaxSource": 'SQL/dataTable.php',
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "bStateSave": true,
    "aoColumns": [
        {"asSorting": [  ], "sClass":"center"},
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null
    ],
    "fnDrawCallback": function() {
        $('.display_results').show();
        $('.def').click(function(){
            var msg = $(this).next().text();
            $('.messages').messageBox({
                'message' : msg,
                'time' : 0, 
                'background' : '#C40000',
                'color' : '#FFF',
                'timeShow' : 1,
                'timeHide' : 1,
                'closeMessage': '', 
                'width' : 350,
                'modal' : 'true',
                'radius' : 7,
                'borderSize' : 3,
                'borderColor' : '#FFF',
                'escape' : 'true'
            });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out a solution:
Gave all columns the type of 'string'. For whatever reason, the default 'html' type was having issues with some of the data.

```
"aoColumns": [{"sType":"string"}]
```